# Get 404 for js files

Tags: python, flask

the header of my flask html template has these 4 lines:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">    
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}"/>    
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js') }}'"></script>    
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}'"></script>
```

I am running flask in debug mode and can see the following output

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2020 12:44:48] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2020 12:44:48] "GET /static/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2020 12:44:48] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2020 12:44:48] "GET /static/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2020 12:44:48] "GET /static/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2020 12:44:48] "GET /static/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2020 12:44:50] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

However the files are there.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 weigla weigla 155758 Feb 13  2019 static/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 weigla weigla  58072 Feb 13  2019 static/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 weigla weigla      0 Mar 24 15:40 static/css/main.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 weigla weigla  88145 May  1  2019 static/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js
```

I don't understand why I get a 404.

Answer (score 1):

I saw it now ....
I have an ' after the closing }}